# Getting Granular Data from Google Analytics to enable Machine Learning applications

Tags: machine-learning, google-analytics

In the context of Google Analytics, I wonder if I can get granular data for an account in the form of a table --or multiple tables that could be joined --containing all relevant information collected per user and then per session.

For each user there should be rows describing in detail the activities and outcomes --micro and macro-- of each session. Features would include source, time of visit, duration of visit, pages visited, time per page, goal conversions etc.

Having the row data in a granular form would enable me to apply machine learning algorithms that would help me explore the data and optimize decisions (web design, budget allocation, biding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, however not by default. You will need to set up custom dimensions to be able to identify individual clients, sessions, and timestamps to be able to get list wise user data, rather then pre-aggregated data. A good place to start is https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/

There is no way to collect all data per user in one simple query. You will need to run multiple queries, pivot tables, etc. and merge's to get the full dataset you are currently envisaging.

Beyond the problem you currently have, there is also then the problem of downloading the data.

1) There is a 10,000 row limit, so you will need to make a loop to download all available rows.

2) Depending on your traffic, you are likely to encounter sampled data, so you will need to download the data per day, or hour to avoid Google Analytics sampling.